# Accumulation point is a limit of some sequences in first-countable space with Axiom of Choice.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, axiom-of-choice

I have a statement which says that

> Let $X$ be a first-countable space and $E$ be a subset of $X$. If $p$
>   is an accumulation point of $E$, then there exists a sequence in $E$ that
>   converges to $p$.

Now I have proved it. The problem is that I think that I had invoked the Axiom of Choice (AC) accidentally. I saw the similar proofs by other people here and they said nothing about AC (See links below). Thus my question is that does my proof here contain AC?.

[Accumulation points of sequences as limits of subsequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192463/accumulation-points-of-sequences-as-limits-of-subsequences)

[In a first-countable space, an accumulation point of the set of terms in a sequence is also a limit-point of the sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145563/in-a-first-countable-space-an-accumulation-point-of-the-set-of-terms-in-a-seque)

Also, There were other people who also had the similar questions, but since they worked in metric space which is stricter than first-countable space, the answer was another proof that can avoided AC (See links below).

[Proving that without the axiom of choice there is a set with an accumulation point that isn'tthe limit of a convergeant sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513214/proving-that-without-the-axiom-of-choice-there-is-a-set-with-an-accumulation-poi)

[(ZF)subsequence convergent to a limit point of a sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183404/zfsubsequence-convergent-to-a-limit-point-of-a-sequence)

I wrote my proof myself below.  If you think it is too long, please see tl;dr

> Let $X$ be a first-countable space, $E\subseteq X$, $p$ be an
>   accumulation point of $E$. Since $X$ is first-countable, there exists
>   a collection of open sets $(U_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $p\in U_i$ for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and for every neighborhood $U$ of $p$,
>   there exists a number $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $U_m\subseteq U$. Next,
>   we let $S_n = \cap_{i=1}^n U_i$. Since each $U_i$ is an open
>   neighborhood of $p$, this implies that $S_n$ is also an open
>   neighborhood of $p$ and thus must contain a point in $E$ which is
>   different from $p$ (i.e., $S_n-\lbrace p\rbrace$ is
>   not empty). This is true for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We also have the
>   fact that $S_n\subseteq U_n$. Thus we have the collection of
>   $(S_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $p$,
>   there exists a number $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $S_m\subseteq U_m\subseteq U$. Now
>   if we '**choose**' a point $p_n\in S_n$ such that $p_n\in E$ for every
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we get a sequence $(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that
>   it is in $E$. Now to show that this sequence converges to $p$, we
>   recall that for every neighborhood $U$ of $p$, there exists a number
>   $m$ such that $S_m\subseteq U$. Hence $p_m \in U$. For every other
>   $n>m$, we note that $S_n\subseteq S_m$. Thus $p_n\in U$ and this implies
>   that $(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ really converges to $p$.

tl;dr

First, I have an infinitely countable collection of non-empty sets. Then I choose an element of each set to construct an infinite sequence. Does this count as using the axiom of choice?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346526/proof-of-a-basic-ac-omega-equivalence should also definitely be mentioned.

Comment: That's amazing. I didn't know that they're actually equivalent in metric space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument uses the [axiom of countable choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice), which says that every countable family of non-empty sets has a choice function. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513214/proving-that-without-the-axiom-of-choice-there-is-a-set-with-an-accumulation-poi) (one of those to which you linked) shows that some amount of choice is needed. The axiom of choice is usually not mentioned in such arguments simply because it’s generally taken for granted in doing topology.

Comment: Thank you! this really confused me because normally people would use convention like stating that they're using AC. Since they didn't mention AC, and some of proofs in metric space explicitly stated that they didn't use AC. I thought that AC has no role here.

Comment: @Tommjjerry: You’re welcome! In general you should not expect explicit mention of the use of $\mathsf{AC}$ in most areas of mathematics: it really is simply taken for granted. (There are exceptions, of course, e.g., set theory itself.)

Comment: @Brian: Most of the explicit use of AC in set theory is when the professor is apologizing to me (jokingly, of course) for using the axiom of choice, in class. Other than that, of course, the subareas where the axiom of choice is explicitly investigated are the obvious exception.

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, I didn’t mean to imply that this was universally the case in set theory. I see that I inadvertently omitted the *in* that was supposed to go before *set theory*.

Comment: By the way, as I showed in the link I added in the comments to the question, the statement is in fact equivalent to countable choice.